# Is it possible to bind the height/width of a pane to the center node of a BorderPane?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an assignment that requires me to extend the pane class, then add a rectangle on it.  I then fill the rectangle and use some buttons to change the colors of the rectangle.  I added my extended Pane class to the center node of the border pane, but I envisioned the rectangle taking up the whole pane and binging to the Pane's height and width, then in turn the Pane taking up the whole center Pane of the BorderPane and bound to the centerPane's height and width. Should I be making a Pane, then adding the Extended Pane to the Pane, then adding the Pane to the BorderPane's Center Pane?  Here's the entirety of my code.  Image of what I get so far below as well.

[image]

```
package homework;

import javafx.scene.shape.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColorSample extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) {
        //Create border pane
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        
        //Create saturation buttons
        Button btnMSat = new Button("More Saturated");
        Button btnLSat = new Button("Less Saturated");
        
        //Create hue buttons
        Button btnHueU = new Button("Hue Up");
        Button btnHueD = new Button("Hue Down");
        
        //Create Darker/Brighter buttons
        Button btnDark = new Button("Darker");
        Button btnBright = new Button("Brighter");
        
        //Create Top and bottom HBoxes
        HBox THBox = new HBox(10);
        THBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox BHBox = new HBox(10);
        BHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        //Create ColorPane
        Color color = Color.MEDIUMBLUE;
        ColorPane cp = new ColorPane(color);
        cp.setColor(color);
        //Set Events
        //More Saturation Clicked
        btnMSat.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setColor(cp.moreSaturation(cp.getColor()));
        });
        //Less Saturation Clicked
        btnLSat.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setColor(cp.lessSaturation(cp.getColor()));
        });
        //Hue Up Clicked
        btnHueU.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setHue(cp.getColor(), 30);
        });
        //Hue Down Clicked
        btnHueD.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setHue(cp.getColor(), -30);
        });
        //Darker Clicked
        btnDark.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.darker(cp.getColor());
        });
        //Brighter Clicked
        btnDark.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.brighter(cp.getColor());
        });
        
        //Add Saturation Buttons to Top HBox
        THBox.getChildren().addAll(btnMSat, btnLSat);
        bp.setTop(THBox);
        //Add Darker/Lighter buttons to Bottom HBox
        BHBox.getChildren().addAll(btnDark, btnBright);
        bp.setBottom(BHBox);
        //Create right side VBox
        VBox RVBox = new VBox(10);
        RVBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        //Add Hue buttons to right side VBox
        RVBox.getChildren().addAll(btnHueU, btnHueD);
        bp.setPrefSize(450, 325);
        bp.setRight(RVBox);
        //Add ColorPane to Border Panel
        bp.setCenter(cp);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(cp, Pos.CENTER);
        
        
        //Create scene and add border pane to it
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 525, 450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    class ColorPane extends Pane {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            
    
        ColorPane() {
            //Set properties
            rectangle.setX(0);
            rectangle.setY(0);
            //Bind width and height
            rectangle.setWidth(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            rectangle.setHeight(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }
        
        ColorPane(Color c) {
            //Set properties
            rectangle.setX(0);
            rectangle.setY(0);
            rectangle.setWidth(450);
            rectangle.setHeight(450);
            //Bind width and height
            rectangle.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            rectangle.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
            setColor(c);
            rectangle.setStroke(c);
            rectangle.setFill(c);
            getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }   
        
        @Override
        public void setWidth(double w) {
            super.setWidth(w);
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void setHeight(double h) {
            super.setWidth(h);
            
        }
        
        public Color setHue(Color color, double h) {
            double newHue = 0;
            
            if(color.getHue() + h >= 360)
                newHue = 360;
            else if (color.getBlue() + h <= 0)
                newHue = 0;
            else
                newHue+=h;
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(newHue, color.getSaturation(),
                    color.getBrightness(), color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color moreSaturation(Color color) {
            double newSat = 0;
            
            if (Math.pow(color.getSaturation(), 2) > 1)
                newSat = 1;
            else
                newSat = Math.pow(color.getSaturation(), 2);
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), newSat,
                    color.getBrightness(), color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color lessSaturation(Color color) {
            double newSat = 0;
            
            if (Math.sqrt(color.getSaturation()) > 0)
                newSat = Math.sqrt(color.getSaturation());
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), newSat,
                    color.getBrightness(), color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color darker(Color color) {
            double brightness = 0;
            if(Math.pow(color.getBrightness(), 2) >=1)
                brightness =1;
            else
                brightness = Math.pow(color.getBrightness(), 2);
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), color.getSaturation(),
                    brightness, color.getOpacity());
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color brighter(Color color) {
            double brightness = 0;
            if(Math.sqrt(color.getBrightness())>0)
                brightness = Math.sqrt(color.getBrightness());
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), color.getSaturation(),
                    brightness, color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color getColor() {
            return (Color) rectangle.getFill();
        }
        
        public void setColor(Color c) {
            rectangle.setStroke(c);
            rectangle.setFill(c);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ... vs _the entirety of my code_ If you struggle with layouts (which seems to be the essence of your assignement, is it?), there's no need for anything except layout related code :) Just a single rectangle, a single button (or two) (color or other domain properties are irrelevant)

Answer (score 0):

Actually set the addition of the ColorPane to the top left position of the center node of the BorderPane with the following then added it to the center:

```
bp.setAlignment(cp, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
bp.setCenter(cp);
```

Still trying to figure out how to deal with the behavior when it resizes, but this is much better.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so in the ColorPane constructors I commented out the lines that bind the height and width, so now the rectangle appears, but while the rectangle starts at coordinates 0,0 of the Pane (See constructors), The ColorPane Itself is not filling the center pane of the Border Pane.  Screenshot and code below.

[image: Rectangle needs to fill center pane, not overlap bottom pane]

```
package homework;

import javafx.scene.shape.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColorSample extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage) {
        //Create border pane
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        
        //Create saturation buttons
        Button btnMSat = new Button("More Saturated");
        Button btnLSat = new Button("Less Saturated");
        
        //Create hue buttons
        Button btnHueU = new Button("Hue Up");
        Button btnHueD = new Button("Hue Down");
        
        //Create Darker/Brighter buttons
        Button btnDark = new Button("Darker");
        Button btnBright = new Button("Brighter");
        
        //Create Top and bottom HBoxes
        HBox THBox = new HBox(10);
        THBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox BHBox = new HBox(10);
        BHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        //Create ColorPane
        Color color = Color.MEDIUMBLUE;
        ColorPane cp = new ColorPane(color);
        cp.setColor(color);
        //Set Events
        //More Saturation Clicked
        btnMSat.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setColor(cp.moreSaturation(cp.getColor()));
        });
        //Less Saturation Clicked
        btnLSat.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setColor(cp.lessSaturation(cp.getColor()));
        });
        //Hue Up Clicked
        btnHueU.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setHue(cp.getColor(), 30);
        });
        //Hue Down Clicked
        btnHueD.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.setHue(cp.getColor(), -30);
        });
        //Darker Clicked
        btnDark.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.darker(cp.getColor());
        });
        //Brighter Clicked
        btnDark.setOnAction(e->{
            cp.brighter(cp.getColor());
        });
        
        //Add Saturation Buttons to Top HBox
        THBox.getChildren().addAll(btnMSat, btnLSat);
        bp.setTop(THBox);
        //Add Darker/Lighter buttons to Bottom HBox
        BHBox.getChildren().addAll(btnDark, btnBright);
        bp.setBottom(BHBox);
        //Create right side VBox
        VBox RVBox = new VBox(10);
        RVBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        //Add Hue buttons to right side VBox
        RVBox.getChildren().addAll(btnHueU, btnHueD);
        //bp.setPrefSize(450, 325);
        bp.setRight(RVBox);
        //Add ColorPane to Center Border Panel
        //Insets inset = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        //bp.setPadding(inset);
        //bp.setAlignment(cp, Pos.CENTER);
        bp.setCenter(cp);
        
        
        //Create scene and add border pane to it
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 525, 450);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    class ColorPane extends Pane {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            
    
        ColorPane() {
            //Set properties
            rectangle.setX(0);
            rectangle.setY(0);
            //Bind width and height
            /*rectangle.setWidth(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            rectangle.setHeight(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);*/
            getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }
        
        ColorPane(Color c) {
            //Set properties
            rectangle.setX(0);
            rectangle.setY(0);
            rectangle.setWidth(450);
            rectangle.setHeight(450);
            //Bind width and height
            /*rectangle.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            rectangle.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());*/
            setColor(c);
            rectangle.setStroke(c);
            rectangle.setFill(c);
            getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }   
        
        @Override
        public void setWidth(double w) {
            super.setWidth(w);
            
        }
        
        @Override
        public void setHeight(double h) {
            super.setWidth(h);
            
        }
        
        public Color setHue(Color color, double h) {
            double newHue = 0;
            
            if(color.getHue() + h >= 360)
                newHue = 360;
            else if (color.getBlue() + h <= 0)
                newHue = 0;
            else
                newHue+=h;
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(newHue, color.getSaturation(),
                    color.getBrightness(), color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color moreSaturation(Color color) {
            double newSat = 0;
            
            if (Math.pow(color.getSaturation(), 2) > 1)
                newSat = 1;
            else
                newSat = Math.pow(color.getSaturation(), 2);
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), newSat,
                    color.getBrightness(), color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color lessSaturation(Color color) {
            double newSat = 0;
            
            if (Math.sqrt(color.getSaturation()) > 0)
                newSat = Math.sqrt(color.getSaturation());
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), newSat,
                    color.getBrightness(), color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color darker(Color color) {
            double brightness = 0;
            if(Math.pow(color.getBrightness(), 2) >=1)
                brightness =1;
            else
                brightness = Math.pow(color.getBrightness(), 2);
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), color.getSaturation(),
                    brightness, color.getOpacity());
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color brighter(Color color) {
            double brightness = 0;
            if(Math.sqrt(color.getBrightness())>0)
                brightness = Math.sqrt(color.getBrightness());
            
            Color output = Color.hsb(color.getHue(), color.getSaturation(),
                    brightness, color.getOpacity());
            
            return output;
        }
        
        public Color getColor() {
            return (Color) rectangle.getFill();
        }
        
        public void setColor(Color c) {
            rectangle.setStroke(c);
            rectangle.setFill(c);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer, is it? Please edit the question with what you tried on the way to a solution - when succeeded, post a single answer with the final result :)